# What is the enforceability of claims if a patent is entered into and under going an Ex-Parté Re-Exam?

Tags: re-exam, ex-parte

Once the USPTO initiates an Ex-parté re-exam on a patent and the claims are being reviewed. What is the enforceability of the claims?

Would the patent owner dare sue for infringement damages when their patent claims are in question?

What would happen if the patent emerges with a complete set of narrower claims that absolve the infringer? Would the patent owner be liable for lawyer fees incurred?